# Build project failed with several semantic issues in PFImageView.h, PFLoginView.h

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

Here I have several issues(semantic) when I run my project which is used to be run successfully. This is a project modified from Parse's Anywall. Issues have been found so far in **PFImageView.h** and **PFLoginView.h**. Please see details from picture below:

[image]

I've been doubting that this may be down to Parse.framework/ParseUI.framework. However, before I go to try to update those frameworks (which I'm sure will cause me a big mess), I'd like to hear from those who may have greater experience on this. Where should I start to look at in order to solve those issues? Thanks a lot in advance.

**Edit:**

After I commented out `@import ParseUI.h` in `SearchViewController.h` following comment from @Putz1103, it eliminated all semantic issues that I have. Now I only have the below issue remaining instead:

[image]

Comment: Those errors are saying that you have included that class twice in your project.  So the first time it is included the compiler creates the classes and objects.  The second time it is included the compiler says "I already did that..." and crashes.  So figure out why it is included twice and remove one of them.

Comment: Right it seems like that but I just don't know why this is happening. I haven't changed or added anything since last time it worked.

Comment: Try removing the `@import ParseUI.h` from your `SearchViewController.h`.  Change any classes needed in the .h file for `@class` instead.  See if that resolves anything.  You may get forward declaration errors, but those can be dealt with easier.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Putz1103 it eliminated all semantic issues but now there remain only one issue. Please see my updated question and kindly let me know what it is.

Comment: My guess to that is that the ParseUI project that you have added to your project includes the FacebookSDK.  So if you include the ParseUI and FacebookSDK into your project then the FacebookSDK is imported twice into the project.  Change that by removing all references of the FacebookSDK in your build phases (link library with binaries).  That is only a guess...

Comment: @Putz1103 I tried removing either FacebookSDK.framework or Bolts.framework but it's not working for me so far. I think I'm going to have a new question for this but for my original question it's solved, so if you can have your answer following your comments here I'll accept that. Thanks again:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem with your project is a double import of the PFImageView class into your project.  The compiler gets asked at one point in your project to add that class to the build.  Then another part of the project requests it again and the compiler throws an error saying it already did that.  This happens a lot with libraries.  A library may import a class that your main project is already using.  Since they are built separately and then linked together after build the compiler doesn't know the duplication exists until after everything is built.  The way of resolving that is to make sure you are only importing each class once (including inside all your libraries).

The second problem is identical to the first.  The problem says `duplicate symbol`.  The compiler is trying to add two of the exact same class or variable to the project.  This is usually due to a duplicated import (and again, usually in libraries in my experience).  Make sure each class you use anywhere is only imported into the project once.  Easier said than done, but it's a good exercise because this comes up with libraries often.